# Access deny on Sharepoint 2010 's search service application

Tags: search, enterprise-search

We have done migration from SharePoint 2007 to 2010, configured its Search Service.

After that the Search service found default web application setting that was created in first step of 2010 installation and this will work for default web application service only
and for next web applications that we have before migration or  create new one and added to the content source list not crawled and ->Type start addresses below field, we will receive this error:

> (((Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access
>   Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl
>   this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint
>   repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read"
>   permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled))))

And in addition, my user has full permission in SQL and SharePoint farm.

Comment: Those URLs don't seem to be compliant to me. Do they actually contain "@" signs?

Comment: You say, your account has full permissions, but is the crawler using your account?

Comment: yes crawler using of my account

Comment: we reconfig everything in the server but this is work only on sharepoint 2010 site and does not work on sharepoint 2007 upgraded sites and web applications